# How can i keep the graphing result of a python function despite while calling it multiple times?

Tags: python, function, matplotlib

I am having fun creating yield curves for a "put" option. I made a function that plots the curves given its arguments. I want to be able to do this for multiple diffrent arguments and display them at the same time to compare. This is what i have so far:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
#counter=1
def my_function(option,strike,bid,price):
    if option=="put":
        breakeven=price-bid
        x=[breakeven-10,breakeven,price,price+bid]
        y=[0]*len(x)
        i=0
        while i<len(x):
            if x[i]<price:
                y[i]=(x[i]*-100) + breakeven*100
            else:
                y[i]=-100*bid
            print(x[i],y[i])
            i+=1
        plt.figure(counter)
        plt.plot(x, y, label = str(strike))
        #naming the x axis
        plt.xlabel('price')
        #naming the y axis
        plt.ylabel('profit')
        plt.show() 
     #counter+=1          
my_function("put",90,20,100)
my_function("put",90,10,100)
```

However, instead of generating another figure, it just replaces it.

I've tried using a global counter and using plt.figure(counter) prior to my plot but it doesnt accept an incrementing counter.

Comment: put ``plt.figure`` outside of your function. Better yet (in my opinion), ``fig, ax = plt.subplots()``, followed by your function but without ``plt.figure``, and instead of ``plt.plot`` write ``ax.plot``

Comment: having a figure-creating-command (``plt.figure``) inside your function basically means that you are creating new figure everytime you call the function

Answer (score 0):

You need to take the `fig, ax = plt.subplots()` out of the loop and also the `plt.show()` to achieve this. Otherwise you are writing over the same plot.

So the code will look like this:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

def my_function(option,strike,bid,price):
    if option=="put":
        breakeven=price-bid
        x=[breakeven-10,breakeven,price,price+bid]
        y=[0]*len(x)
        i=0
        while i<len(x):
            if x[i]<price:
                y[i]=(x[i]*-100) + breakeven*100
            else:
                y[i]=-100*bid
            # print(x[i],y[i])
            i+=1
        ax.plot(x, y, label = str(strike))
        #naming the x axis
        ax.set_xlabel('price')
        #naming the y axis
        ax.set_ylabel('profit')
        # plt.show()  <-- remove this !!
         
my_function("put",90,20,100)
my_function("put",90,10,100)

# plot all lines
plt.show()
```

and the result will look like this:

[image]

Comment: that is basically exactly the same answer as the one I submitted before...

Comment: @Karina, the previous answer makes a good attempt to the point that it moves `fig, ax` outside of the loop but fails to move `plt.show()` outside (although it correctly comments it out inside the loop) which would therefore leave the question incomplete. The answer here explains the issue, corrects it, and provides a working outcome...  so the answers are similar, but far from being the same.

Comment: and I provided that information in the comment section before I uploaded an answer.

Answer (score -1):

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

plt.close()
fig, ax = plt.subplots()

def my_function(option,strike,bid,price):
    if option=="put":
        breakeven=price-bid
        x=[breakeven-10,breakeven,price,price+bid]
        y=[0]*len(x)
        i=0
        while i<len(x):
            if x[i]<price:
                y[i]=(x[i]*-100) + breakeven*100
            else:
                y[i]=-100*bid
            # print(x[i],y[i])
            i+=1
        ax.plot(x, y, label = str(strike))
        #naming the x axis
        ax.set_xlabel('price')
        #naming the y axis
        ax.set_ylabel('profit')
        # plt.show() 
         
my_function("put",90,20,100)
my_function("put",90,10,100)
```